# What can i control when i restoring a databese? For example can i OverWrite the existing databse?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, t-sql

Im building a program who can restore a database from a .bak file. I want to know if i can get the path for mdf and log file for a specific database from a tsql script?

Comment: With a SQL Server using an mdf file if you are restoring the entire database the easiest way is to make a copy of the mdf file.  So we usually deattach the database.  Copy the mdf file and then attached the mdf file.  When we want to restore we simply attach the mdf file.  You can always rename the mdf and attach so you have multiple copies of the same database.  The restore method changes the ownership of the database and can get messy.  Usually an Admin has to do backups.

Comment: I solved it myself. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `WITH MOVE` option of the `RESTORE` command. See the Example D in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

To find the correct syntax you can also use SSMS and use the "Script" button in the "Restore Database" dialog.